# Any good service where I can see if a domain is blacklisted by Google or not?

Tags: seo, google, domains, blacklist

I have found a site from one of my friend said that this link is forwarded by godaddy support. http://onlinealley.com/seotools/googlebannedchecker/

But I don't think its result is right because i have a domain which is working right and well indexed its showing is banned. Also i have checked for couple of domains which are open for registration is also saying banned by that site.

Can you recommend any other service that gives right information? That will help me when buy domains from auctions or already registered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn't publish this information so any service you find this kind of information will not be complete and it will be speculative in nature.

If you do purchase a new domain and it appears to have issues with Google, you can always file an re-inclusion request with Google stating that you are the new owner and the site follows their guidelines.

Comment: The re-inclusion request. How can i do it? Should i just contact them or its a part of any google service (google webmaster etc)?

Comment: Check this [Google help page](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35843) for more information about it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways I go about checking the integrity of a previously registered or expiriing domain name that I intend to purchase.

1. Do a Google search site:yourdomain.com and see if Google still has anything in its index. Not a big deal of not but if any pages are indexed its fine.
2. Use archive.org to see what was previously hosted on the domain. Look for anything suspicious like spammy/junk content.
3. Check email blacklists. Sometimes a domain may not actually have been used to host a site but used an email spam relay. Use something like http://www.blacklistalert.org
4. Page rank check. Use http://www.seomoz.org/toolbox/pagerank. Expiring or recently expired domain names can often still display page rank. No page rank does not necessarily mean the domain is/has been banned.

Hope this helps!