# Checking if domain will be blacklisted in advance?

Tags: domains, blacklist

I've chosen a name for my next website, let's say `example.com` - but I noticed that the url `example.de` is used for pornographic content (some links to other pornographic sites) and `example.net` is dead now but did so some years ago.

The words used in the domain aren't anything "fancy" and I shouldn't necessarily trigger a blacklisting.
But I'm worried that due to the other two sites (`example.de` is already blacklisted by at least Avira) my new site will be blacklisted as well.

**tl;dr**
How can I check whether popular firewalls will block my domain *before* I go and register it?

**Edit**
I've read these two questions ([[1]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17788/any-good-service-where-i-can-see-if-a-domain-is-blacklisted-by-google-or-not?rq=1), [[2]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24992/how-do-i-check-if-a-domain-is-blacklisted-before-buying-it?rq=1)), but my case appears to be somehow different as I'm not buying an already existing domain but registering it for the very first time.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the reputation of the domain by search engines.

Comment: are two domain still working ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Checking RHSBL & LHSBL Blacklists*

I'd recommend [Blacklist Alert](http://www.blacklistalert.org/), [Ultratools](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/spamDBLookup) and [Mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)  which checks both RHSBL and LHSBL across various networks such as RFC-Ignorant, Anonwhois, dnsbl, spamhaus and dozens more.

*Reputation Check*

Also worth checking out what trust and review sites say about the domain i.e these:

- [TrustPilot](https://www.trustpilot.co.uk/)
- [Norton Safe Web](https://safeweb.norton.com/)
- [Web of Trust aka WOT](https://www.mywot.com/)
- [McAfee Site Adviser](https://www.siteadvisor.com/)

*Backlink Checker*

Back-links can be the most harmful SEO factor that Google and other search engines take into consideration when working out rankings, it used to be more the better but nowadays its about quality and relevancy. If a domain that your interested in has lots of links from 'Cooking Sites' but you want to use it for 'CARS' then depending on the number of links this could actually go against you at a later date. Also worth noting that most 'free backlink checkers' are useless, go for something like [Majestic SEO](http://www.majesticseo.com/), [SEO Profiler](http://www.seoprofiler.com/) or  [Moz](http://moz.com/tools).

*Social Media*

Another important factor when purchasing a domain is has it been used on social media? if so are those pages still active, these can damage reputation, confuse SEO and your visitors, social media is often a pain in the arse to get pages, accounts disabled unless you apply for a trademark.

Answer (score 2):

You have far less to worry about than you think. But there are things to look for.

All blacklists are based upon domainname.tld and/or IP address at it's base. In the case that you cited, example.com will not be blacklisted because example.net or example.de has become blacklisted unless they are related by ownership, registration, or host.

If example.com and example.net are hosted on the same IP address, share the same registration details, are within the same -reserved- IP address block, and so on where it becomes obvious that the two domains are related, then one might effect the other. If, however, there is no relationship between the two, then you are okay.

Check the registration of doth domain names by doing a `nslookup domainname.tld` or `whois domainname.tld`. If they match, then you have a concern up and until the point that the registration changes again. Check to see if the domain names resolve by doing a dig domainname.tld any and see if they share an IP address block or ISP. It may not always be clear, but you will see similar IP addresses if so. Then you may have some concern. Otherwise, you should be clear.